# issue loading google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am having one main activity in which i am having one button when this button is pressed it shows the Map.This works perfect.

But when i am pressing the back key i am again going to my main activity and now when once again i am pressing the button for Map it shows whole world map.

I mean to say it starts from the scratch.

How can i completely remove my map activity from Back Stack and create again to show Map once again as i wanted?

Or Any other Solutions to do it?

**EDIT:1**

```
btn_find_atm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NearByATM.this, Map.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, request_map);

        }
    });
```

**EDIT:2**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (isGooglePlayAvailable()) {

        expld = new ExpandablePlaceListData();

        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        // Getting the service from context and giving to location_manager
        location_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        setContentView(R.layout.mapdemo);

        placesTask = new PlacesTask();

        getGoogleMap();

        getUserLocation();

        google_map.clear();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude:" + lat + " Longitude:" + lang,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        drawMarker();

        sb = createUrl();

        placesTask.execute(sb);

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    this.finish();
}
```

**EDIT:3**

```
private void getUserLocation() {

    if (location_manager != null) {
        provider = location_manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = location_manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                Map.MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                Map.MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lang = location.getLongitude();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Unable to idntify location",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            lat = -22.00000;
            lang = 33.0000;

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:4**

LogCat shows something like these when i am again pressing button to load map.

```
10-19 16:47:06.048: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:06.086: I/SurfaceTexture(4887): [unnamed-4887-1](this:0x5fa6d608,api:0) detachFromContext
10-19 16:47:06.087: I/BufferQueue(4887): [unnamed-4887-1](this:0x610cd580,api:0) consumerDisconnect
10-19 16:47:06.088: I/BufferQueue(4887): [unnamed-4887-1](this:0x610cd580,api:0) ~BufferQueue
10-19 16:47:06.090: D/dalvikvm(4887): threadid=22: exiting
10-19 16:47:06.096: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:06.097: D/dalvikvm(4887): threadid=22: bye!
10-19 16:47:08.782: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.783: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.785: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.853: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.853: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.854: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.864: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.864: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.865: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.866: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.866: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.867: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.874: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-19 16:47:08.882: W/Trace(4887): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: you should put up your code so people can tell you what they think

Comment: @JRowan what code you want i am starting activity?

Comment: im just not getting the question, you press the button and it shows you the map how you want it? then you press back and if you press the button again it doesnt show the map how you want it?

Comment: @JRowan i am finding location and i am zooming to that and putting marker and when i am going back and starting map again it gives the WORLD view so the zoom is not done as well as marker is also not coming. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: are you sending result from Map.class to NearByATM?

Comment: `OnBackpress()` You should finish your `Map` activity. @google

Comment: @GrIsHu i am doing same but still not working i am firing finish();

Comment: can you put up your Map Activity?

Comment: how about getUserLocation(); because what im thinking is when you requestlocationupdates you are leaving your location listener running maybe and not removinglocationupdates before you finish() maybe

Comment: @JRowan i think you are right can you tell me what can i do?

Comment: how are you using getUserLocation() method?

Comment: location_manager.removeUpdates(this); before finish();

Comment: @JRowan still not done.

Comment: is it any different or just still world map thats it

Comment: @JRowan just world map.

Comment: @google Have you implemented `onActivityResult` in your `NearByATM.this` activity to get the result back.

Comment: doesnt AsyncTask only run once, thats it you cant run it twice

Comment: @google Please always make habit of posting the logcat error with your question if you are getting any kind of error.

Comment: @JRowan i am running AsyncTask only once to run more i am creating new object that is the placesTask.

Comment: @GrIsHu there is no error. my problem is i am not getting the again map with zoom and marker and also execute the AsyncTask.

Comment: your not sending back data anyway why dont you just use startActivity() instead of startActivityForResult()

Comment: @JRowan i already tried with start activity then i modified to startActivityForResult() help me out yar.

Comment: im stuck at this point, i dont know what to tell you

Comment: @google Have you read my comment first ? I asked you have you implemented `onActivityResult` in your `NearByATM.this` to get result back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally what i have done is,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    google_map.clear();
    location_manager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

and on the Activity Result i removed the all the activities from the back stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NearByATM.this, NearByATM.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and on Manifiest file in Main activity i removed from history too,

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a LocationClient and Location manager and also ** you don't have to bother about removing activity from back stack** or any other thing. Let android system handle that for you.

Implement `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` in your activity..

implement all the necessary methods.

```
LocationClient lc = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

public void onStart()
{
     super.onStart();
     lc.connect();
}
```

.....
In the same class in the implemented methods....
do your necessary work in 
`public void onConnected(Bundle b) {}` 
and 
`public void ondisConnected(Bundle arg0) {}`

This is the best I can tell you from seeing your code. As there are too many methods you have called and I can not see the implementation of the methods.
If you implement this mechanism you dont have to handle **onBackPressed()** or any of the other handles.

Some code....

```
public class Example extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle arg0)
{
// Initialize LocationClient here. and do necessary things.
}

public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    lc.connect();
}

public void onPause()
{
   // Remove object references and reset the map components if you want
}
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0)
{
     // This will be called when you use lc.connect();  and the connection is successful otherwise onConnectionfailed() if connection fails.
     // If connected then do necessary things on GOOGLE MAPS here.
     // Whatever your code is, put here what you have shown in the sample code.
     gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(YOUR_LATLNG_HERE, 15.00f));
     // The above statement will move your camera to the location with zooming and animation. 15.00f is the zoom level. you can change it.
}

public void onDisconnected(Bundle arg0)
{
     // Do on disconnect  
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0)
{
    // Do something or leave blank if on connection failed.
}
}
```

This example assumes that you have a mapfragment in your activity layout. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you have example where i have to do what? i referred this link http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html but changing everything remains comparatively difficult.

Comment: you have to change your mechanism a little bit to make this work. this is efficient and is the right way to do it. I have done the same mistake I will make edit in the answer with the code. you can refer to that.

Comment: there will be need of location manager when using location client?

Comment: no. there is no  need of location manager for location client. And if you want to zoom in a particular location then use can use `gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(YOUR_LATLNG_HERE, 15.00f));`  in onConnected() method. where YOUR_LATLNG_HERE is the LatLng of the location you want to zoom in and 15.00f is the zoom level.

Comment: This will animate the camera to your location with specified zoom level and it looks pretty good. Please check the edit. So if you switch to this activity every time its going to set the zoom to your marker.

Comment: is there no any other way?In this case i really have to change my whole code i mean to say not whole but will need many corrections.

Comment: Isn't that you want. just put your code into the code I provided above or in the right place. you can always call the same methods from there. This is the right mechanism and really easy way to achieve what you are trying to achieve. the link http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html . also specifics the same thing. if you take a look at the example.

Comment: I have made a generalized class which helps some problems with google maps. I am willing to upload that to github but It is unfinished. I will post ASAP and specify a link here.

Comment: Hey brother sorry to inform you but i tried the code that provided by you and i added my code at particular position but it happens the same.I mean to say it generates the same problem.

Comment: can you specify what these 3 methods do?  getGoogleMap(), getUserLocation(), google_map.clear() ?